# How to reset navigator with using NavigationService in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using [NavigationService method](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html) in React Navigation by developing my apps. I have an Auth page which is developed with Redux. When user logged in Auth page, the page is linked to Main Page.

But, I can return to Auth page with sliding (in IOS) or pushing to back button (in Android). How can i reset navigator after the user logged in or pass the Auth page?

Here is the my function for login process below:

```
const loginSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {

   console.log('LOGINSUCCESS --> OK!');
  return dispatch => {
    NavigationService.navigate('Main');
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
      payload: user,
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

First of all, i want to show my `NavigationService.js` codes below:

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from "react-navigation";

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    }),
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  navigateReset,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```

Then, I have added some codes for reset the navigator. (It means when you pass the next screen but never come back again with swiping or Android Back button.)

```
function navigateReset(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName,
          params,
        }),
      ],
    }),
  );
}
```

Finally, I have edited my Action code with new function:

```
const loginSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/users/' + user.user.uid)
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user,
        myUser: {
          uid: user.user.uid,
          email: user.user.email,
          name: snapshot.val().displayName,
          groups: snapshot.val().groups,
        },
      });
    });

  dispatch(() => {
    NavigationService.navigateReset('Main'); // Edited code.
  });

  console.log('LOGINSUCCESS --> OK!');
};
```

Taa taa! Congrulations! Now, you never back to Login screen after Logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require to return from the method. It will directly move to a particular screen.

```
dispatch(
    NavigationService.navigate('Main')
  );
```

Comment: It didn't work. :( Can you edit your answer with NavigationService method?

Comment: It's not wrong totally (but you should fix ``'Main`` to ``'Main'``), it's working but not resetting navigator. Only changing screen.

Comment: Its typo mistake.